# SQL Command to convert pgRouting result to GeoJSON

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, sql, geojson

My goal is to produce a Web UI for pgRouting using [this tutorial](http://www.mkgeomatics.com/wordpress/?p=330). I have already imported my data from an OSM pBF to PostGIS using osm2po. Using the pgRoutingLayer plugin for QGIS, I was able to figure out the SQL code to create routes using driving time as the cost.

```
SELECT ways.*, route.cost AS route_cost FROM ways JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM shortest_path(
    'SELECT gid AS id, 
            source::int4 AS source, 
            target::int4 AS target, 
            cost::float8 AS cost,
            reverse_cost::float8 AS reverse_cost FROM ways',
            62,19169, True, True)) 
    AS route ON ways.gid= route.edge_id;
```

My next step is to convert this into GeoJSON as done in [Part 1](http://www.mkgeomatics.com/wordpress/?p=312) of the tutorial. This is what seemed logical:

```
SELECT * INTO export
FROM ways.*, route.cost AS route_cost FROM ways JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM shortest_path(
    'SELECT gid AS id, 
            source::int4 AS source, 
            target::int4 AS target, 
            cost::float8 AS cost,
            reverse_cost::float8 AS reverse_cost FROM ways',
            62,19169, True, True)) 
    AS route ON ways.gid= route.edge_id;
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_UNION(the_geom)) AS geom_union
FROM export;

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ","
LINE 2:  FROM ways.*, route.cost AS route_cost FROM ways JOIN (
                    ^
```

but I can't get it to work. Honestly, I'm not very well acquainted with SQL, can someone point out my mistake?

edit: This seems to work, but does it do the same thing?

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE route_result AS 
SELECT ways.*, route.cost AS route_cost FROM ways JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM shortest_path(
    'SELECT gid AS id, 
            source::int4 AS source, 
            target::int4 AS target, 
            cost::float8 AS cost,
            reverse_cost::float8 AS reverse_cost FROM ways',
            62,19169, True, True)) 
    AS route ON ways.gid= route.edge_id; 
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_UNION(the_geom)) AS geom_union 
FROM route_result;
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_UNION(b.the_geom)) AS geojson 
    FROM shortest_path('SELECT ... FROM ...',<start>,<end>,true,true) a,
         ways b 
    WHERE a.edge_id = b.id;
```

This should return the route as a single geometry.